# VBA - Update values in an array with For Each statement

Tags: arrays, vba, foreach

I'm trying yo update my arrays full of numerical values, once I know which Regional settings are set on the computer.

I used this code :

```
If Application.International(xlCountrySetting) <> 33 Then
    For Each x In Country
        x = Replace(x, ",", ".")
    Next x
Else
    For Each x In Country
        x = Replace(x, ".", ",")
    Next x
End If
```

When I debug, I see that **`x` has been changed**, but later on in code, the **values in Array haven't been modified**.

I know I can use `For i = LBound(Country,1) to UBound(Country,1)` but I was wondering if there is a **way to do this with the `For Each` statement**.

Any idea?

Comment: When you say "numerical values", do you mean string representations of numbers? Otherwise it doesn't make much sense trying to replace a character in a numeric value. It would be helpful to show your definition of Country and a sample value that you put into the array.

Comment: It is decimal values, and my problem is that regarding Regional Setting these values are either numerical (good match between decimal separator and regional settings) or string (no match). But my problem is that these loops don't have any effect on the actual array values. The replace work just fine.

Comment: So your array is of type Variant?

Comment: Yup, generally I simply declare it like this `Dim Country()` and here, I tried both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the `For Each` loop is that `x` is a separate variable to `Country` (you had to declare it earlier in your code) and is being set to the value of the current element of `Country`; it is not sharing the same memory, i.e. it is not "by ref".

So when you replace the character in `x` you are only changing `x` and not changing the element in `Country`.

You can see this by adding `Country` to a Watch window, and if you step thru your code you will see that as you iterate through the loop the elements of Country do not change.

However when you use a `For` loop, and use `Country(i) = Replace(Country(i), ".", ",")`, then you are modifying the `Country` element and so the value changes.

Comment: In situation, I will give an array in function argument with different dimensions and elements count. I need using `For Each` in this case and validate each element of array.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this.  I needed to change the value of a Collection in VBA while looping through.

Trying to modify the Collection using a for loop brought an error.  Then like R3uK’s question shows, when I modified the Collection in a foreach loop the value in the Collection didn’t change.

What I did was use another Collection variable for my final answer.  So I would add each value to the new Collection as I looped through.  Then I had a Collection of the data I wanted.

So if “Country" was a Collection, my VBA answer would look like this:

```
Dim Country As New Collection
Dim finalCountry As New Collection

If Application.International(xlCountrySetting) <> 33 Then
    For Each x In Country
        x = Replace(x, ",", ".")
        finalCountry.Add x
    Next x
Else
    For Each x In Country
        x = Replace(x, ".", ",")
        finalCountry.Add x
    Next x
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

For Each is faster than for loop and can be seen when using large arrays or nested loops. Unfortunately, with For Each there is not a built-in element giving the iteration number so you have to place a counter.  It seems as though this defeats the simplicity of the For Each but the speed savings is still realized.  With that here is code that will work and retain the speed benefits of the For Each statement:

```
i = 0
If Application.International(xlCountrySetting) <> 33 Then
    For Each x In Country
        i = i + 1
        Country(i) = Replace(x, ",", ".")
    Next x
Else
    For Each x In Country
        i = i + 1
        Country(i) = Replace(x, ".", ",")
    Next x
End If
```

Comment: Answers claiming speed improvements should cite or provide evidence

Comment: The speed advantage of for each over the for loop in collections is generally known and has previously been addressed several  times on stackoverflow as well as other sites.